# Is there easiest way to derive variance of continuation-ratio logit estimator?

Tags: self-study, variance, delta-method, ordered-logit

I wanted to calculate the variance of continuation-ratio logit estimator that defined as $\hat{\theta}^+_j=\ln\frac{\pi_j}{\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_k}$, for $j=2,...,C$, where $C$ is number of categories.

I have used Delta method (according to John Lachin book), however, work with matrices is way too long (write down and multiply three matrices). Is there shorter way to show that
$Var(\hat{\theta}^+_j)=\frac{1}{N}\bigg[\frac{1}{\pi_j}+\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_k}\bigg]$? Or can you explain me why $Var(\ln\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_k)=\frac{1-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_k}{N\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_k}$?